# Python: how to print consecutive lines after pattern matching

Tags: python, shell

I have 2 files annotation.txt and motif_list.txt. I am stuck at a point where I have to print the next consecutive lines  after I match a pattern, until the next pattern comes. The number of lines after each pattern is variable. The pattern always has "/Homer" at the end. Need a bit of help. Thanks

annotation.txt

```
AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer
gene1
gene2
gene3
ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer
gene1
gene5
gene4
gene10
--------------------------------
```

motif_list.txt

```
AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
E2F4(E2F)/K562-E2F4-ChIP-Seq(GSE31477)/Homer    ERF
ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
```

Code:

```
    import re
    file1 = open("annotation.txt", "r")
    file2 = open("motif_list.txt", "r")
    annot=file1.readlines()
    motif=file2.readlines()
    for i in annot:
    if re.search("/Homer", i):
        for j in motif:
            motif_info=j.split("\t")
            if motif_into[0]==i:
                print the next few lines until the next motif comes, "\t", i, "\t", motif_into[1]
```

Desired output:

```
gene1    AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
gene2    AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
gene3    AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
gene1    ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
gene5    ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
gene4    ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
gene10    ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your motif_list in a dictionary containing the common part (i.e. before /Homer) and use it to carry a line extension pattern over to every line (that is not a pattern header) in annotation.txt:

*note: I used strings to test but you can get the actual data from the files (as indicated in the comments below the big strings)*

**Setup:**

```
motifs = """AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
E2F4(E2F)/K562-E2F4-ChIP-Seq(GSE31477)/Homer    ERF
ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF""".split("\n")

# with f as open('motif_list.txt.txt'):
#    motifs = f.read().split("\n")
                                                                   
annotations = """AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer
gene1
gene2
gene3
ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer
gene1
gene5
gene4
gene10""".split("\n")

# with f as open('annotation.txt'):
#    annotations = f.read().split("\n")
```

**Process:**

```
HOMER = "/Homer"
motifDict = dict(m.split(HOMER,1) for m in motifs)
pattern = ""
for anno in annotations:
    if HOMER in anno:
        pattern = anno+motifDict[anno.split(HOMER,1)[0]]
    else:
        print(anno + "\t" + pattern)
```

**Output:**

```
gene1   AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
gene2   AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
gene3   AT1G10720(BSD)/col-AT1G10720-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    BSD
gene1   ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
gene5   ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
gene4   ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
gene10  ERF3(AP2EREBP)/colamp-ERF3-DAP-Seq(GSE60143)/Homer    ERF
```